# How To Make Microsoft AutoUpdate Update Automatically on a Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, office-for-mac

Lots of programs that I run on my mac update themselves automatically in the background without any action required by me.  The ones that come to mind immediately are Chrome, Dropbox, and Plex.

Given that this is clearly a solved engineering problem, why does Microsoft AutoUpdate parade it's updates in front of my face multiple times a week?  Why do I *ever* need to see the screen shown below:

[image]

Is there a setting I'm missing?  Is there a platform limitation I'm not considering on OS X? Maybe ask me about big updates, but I'm talking about the biweekly bug fixes.  Can't I just opt in?

Or...  Is this just some combination of bad engineering/a desire to make clear just how much I'm getting in exchange for my 9.99/month?

Comment: You're not missing a setting. MS is missing the concept of how to silently auto-update as a background task. I've been trying for months. It's futile. The last couple of releases have improved by allowing the update window to only appear when you actually have updates but you still need to select/acknowledge them and enter your p/w to perform the install.

Comment: Related: https://ianmcdowell.net/blog/mau/